# Micronaut AWS Lambda logs are not showing in cloudfront

Tags: java, logging, aws-lambda, micronaut

I setup a micronaut java aws lambda project like explained here:
https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-function-aws-lambda/guide/index.html

In the main function of the Function class I have an example:

```
System.out.println("LOG TEST LOG LOG");
```

Running locally as described in the documentation via

```
echo '{"param1": "23"}' | java -jar build/lib/myjar-full.jar
```

Shows correctly the console output.

Running the same function online in AWS lambda, does not log that message in cloudwatch logs.

The same problem happens also running locally via SAM CLI as explained in Micronaut docs.

Also using slf4j logger, still I am not getting the output. 
I am providing below all the relevant code of my micronaut lambda function

```
package lambda.test;

import io.micronaut.function.executor.FunctionInitializer;
import io.micronaut.function.FunctionBean;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.util.function.Function;

@FunctionBean("example-lambda")
public class LambdaFunction extends FunctionInitializer implements Function<Request, Response> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getSimpleName());


    /**
     * This main method allows running the function as a CLI application using: echo '{}' | java -jar function.jar
     * where the argument to echo is the JSON to be parsed.
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("LOG TEST LOG LOG");
        logger.info(String.format("Received the following payload: %s", String.join(";", args)));
        LambdaFunction function = new LambdaFunction();
        function.run(args, (context) -> function.apply(context.get(Request.class)));
    }
```

I also created `log4j2.xml` config file in the resources, with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The default `logback.xml` config that comes with micronaut has these content:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <withJansi>true</withJansi>
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%cyan(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %gray([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %magenta(%logger{36}) - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Both ways of trying to log are not working online or with SAM CLI.
I am still researching on how to do this, but so far I cannot find any information on their documentation or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The default Micronaut application when deployed on AWS lambda needs to send logs to CloudWatch. I notice you had only listed STDOUT appenders, which could be the reason for logs not showing up on CloudWatch.

Add a CloudWatch appender; something like this:

```
    <appender name="CLOUDWATCH" class="io.micronaut.aws.cloudwatch.logging.CloudWatchLoggingAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
            <jsonFormatter class="io.micronaut.aws.cloudwatch.logging.CloudWatchJsonFormatter"/>
            <!-- Define the custom fields using %X -->
            <pattern>
                {
                "timestamp": "%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}",
                "level": "%level",
                "message": "%msg",
                "AWSRequestId": "%X{AWSRequestId}",
                "AWSFunctionName": "%X{AWSFunctionName}",
                "AWSFunctionVersion": "%X{AWSFunctionVersion}",
                "AWSXRayTraceId": "%X{AWS-XRAY-TRACE-ID}"
                }
            </pattern>
            <logEntrySeparator></logEntrySeparator>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Feel free to remove the pattern and any other bells and whistles.

Also as a side note, I noticed you have turned Jansi on, so make sure to include the required library in your Maven or Gradle dependencies.

Regarding SAM CLI, by which I assume you mean:

```
> sam local
```

You could do something like this to print logs in a log file:

```
sam local start-api --template sam-template-local.yaml --log-file sam-local.log
```

Also, you don't need any specific logger dependency in case you are using Micronaut logging dependency, just the slf4j wrapper to go with it, like (in build.gradle)

```
implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-aws-cloudwatch-logging")
implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api")
```